# How to show several objects with for loop in get_context_data

Tags: python, django

I have requests_cache and i want to show parsed info from json on my page with get_context_data

But it shows only first dict with values and if i place context after for loop it shows second one how to fix that?

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super(ShowProjectBudgetList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    session = requests_cache.CachedSession('project_budget_cache')
    url = config('REPORT_PROJECT_BUDGET')
    response = session.get(url=url, auth=UNICA_AUTH).json()

    for item in response:
        my_js = json.dumps(item)

        parsed_json = ReportProjectBudgetSerializer.parse_raw(my_js)

        obj = parsed_json.ObjectGUID

        context['response_json'] = obj
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you are trying to achieve is a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)).

You can do it several ways in python. Here, since you have several modifications to make, you could either make a function or, probably easier, append to an array.

```py
    context["reponse_json"] = []
    for item in response:
        my_js = json.dumps(item)

        parsed_json = ReportProjectBudgetSerializer.parse_raw(my_js)

        obj = parsed_json.ObjectGUID

        context['response_json'].append(obj)
    return context
```

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (shinier, not necessarily easier to understand)

```
get_GUID = lambda item: ReportProjectBudgetSerializer.parse_raw(json.dumps(item)).ObjectGUID

context["reponse_json"] = [get_GUID(item) for item in reponse]
```